# How to track the code responsible for Heap growth in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks, mbprogresshud

I have spent few days working on this issue. That my app is getting crashed in iPod Touch due to Memory leak.

I have monitored heap growth exactly by Instrument in Xcode and it is confirmed that code is making memory occupied by app grow on each event.

I need to mention here that I am using ARC and hence i was really not expecting app to crash because of memory issue, although ARC isn't helpful incase Core foundation is used but I haven't used Core foundation in my app directly. 
But MBProgressHUD is added in my app which uses this framework. I have not enabled ARC for MBProgressHUD as it was causing lot of memory grow.

I still am unable to track the main problem/variable/code which is causing my app memory to grow so much and causing app to crash.

P.S : Instrument had shown few functions causing lot of memory allocation but in those functions also I don't know how to free those variables as ARC is enabled (It is managed automatically).

Please suggest if I am in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is it leaking or allocation is more? main cause for the app slow down is using too many number of autorelease objects.

Comment: Number of auto release object is indirectly proportional to app performance

Comment: So, 

1. Use as much less autorelease object.

2. Try to neglect allocation inside loop.

3. Reuse pointer variable

4. Reduce number of object allocation in any data source method.
For better performance.

Comment: Well, Thats for preventing it further. I had asked that how should get to the function/ file which is causing heap growth? There might be particular code causing trouble.I want to get to that